# Can xcode insert stubs for all methods you have to implement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When you want certain functionality you have to implement methods, is it possible for xcode to insert stubs for you to do this?

i.e. sometimes you do soething like:

```
UIViewController  <blah>, <blah2>
```

How you have to implement the e.g. delegate methods and datasource methods, is it possible for xcode to stub these out?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this isn't possible. (That said, you might get another answer that has some cunning solution.)

However, a lot of the delegate methods are optional, so you'd quite likely end up with some method stubs that you wouldn't necessarily want to use anyway and the presence of the stubs would potentially cause issues unless they were commented out, by which point you might as well have just copied the method signatures from the relevant protocol reference anyway. :-)

Comment: That's too bad. Maybe someday xcode will have the equivalent of the eclipse "override/implement" methods helper -- which also avoids the problem you point out of too many method stubs. You just choose the ones you want! (But it's nice to easily see the ones that are available without finding the references somewhere else.)

Comment: @lilbyrdie: True, switching from Eclipse to XCode is like trading your car for a tricycle ...

Answer (score 0):

XCode 4 has something like that. You just have to write the beginning of the method name and XCode will complete it with all arguments as placeholders.
Anyway, the fourth version is still in beta, which means that you have to be enrolled in a paid Developer Program (Mac or iOS, 99$ each) to download it and that it potentially have bugs.

These aren't true stubs, but they're really useful because you have just to write 3 or 4 letters to get out a list of all possible methods, with priority to those methods that are part of a protocol or that you've already declared in the interface.

Comment: Xcode 3.x does that as well in general (not sure if it does it for delegate methods though, so perhaps that's different).